# How to set the font-size of the body relative to the screensize

Tags: javascript, html, css

Well, I am currently working on something, but now I am building a mobile version, and for that mobile version I wanted to set the text size relative to the window. I tried to do this:

```
// Getting the right font-size
var viewportWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = (viewportHeight / 10);
```

But for some reason it gives me tells me this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cannot read 'style' of type undefined.
```

Could you guys help me with this, or is there another way, (mayby with css) to solve my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever tried doing this with media queries? See [this for more info](http://joshnh.com/2011/07/26/are-you-using-ems-with-your-media-queries/)

Comment: set font size in points instead of pixels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply this:

```
document.addEventListener('load', function(){
   var viewportWidth  = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
   var viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
   document.body.style.fontSize = (viewportHeight / 10);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is telling you that `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` gives you `undefined`. Therefore you don't have a body element at the time the script runs (so you can't change its style).

Either:

- Move it out of the `head`
- Turn it into a function can call when the document is read / loaded / etc

---

Also, the CSS font-size property takes a length and lengths require units.

Answer (score 0):

Try document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize = (viewportHeight / 10) + "px";

Or any other unit you want to work with.

Also have a look here it might be what you're looking for

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/